# ASP.NET Core Linq query for lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this query that was recently changed to allow searches using lists. However, the logic doesn't seem correct. My initial search logic was as follows:

```
data = data.where(u=>u.location.contains(FilterInput.RepositoryName)).ToList();
```

This worked for individual inputs and the logic made sense. In the data result, check if location field contains the Input variable

However in order to handle inputs that are lists, I had to change it to the bottom code which is in this Input list, check if the it contains the location field.

The database outputs data as follows:

Output = {arhde, brhje, ckio}

That means my list input is a small section of what the database contains.

```
FilterInput.RepositoryName = {a,b,c}

data = (from item in dbContext.Documents
        join id in initialData
        on item.Id equals id.DocumentId
        select new DocumentsListViewModel
        {
            Id = item.Id,
            Name = item.Name,
            ApplicationName = item.ApplicationName,
            ApplicationSecretKey = item.ApplicationSecretKey,
            Link = item.Link,
            Location = item.Location,
            FileType = item.FileType,
            CreatedOn = item.CreatedOn
        }).ToList();

if (FilterInput.RepositoryName.Count>0)
{
    data = data.Where(u => FilterInput.RepositoryName.Contains(u.Location)).ToList();
}
```

I don't know if its possible to change this logic to use the first one but accomodate lists as well?

Comment: Can you add RepositoryName definition?

Comment: RepositoryName input from user is {a,b,c} and u.Location from the database is {ageha,bailey,crown}

Comment: RepositoryName is an input from user and is it a list of string with values ageha,bailey,crown ?

Comment: No RepositoryName is an input from the user and it’s a list of values a,b,c

Comment: What a,b,c represent ? Are they objects? If so what type of objects?

Comment: They are just strings. A,b,c are part of the word that I want to search for

Comment: Is that `u.Location` is also a `List<string>` like `FilterInput.RepositoryName`? If both of them are list of strings, then you seem want to do something called "partial matching".